# SQL remove duplicate row depend on certain value

Tags: sql

I spend day in hope to figure out how to solve this query.

I have following table

```
ID  Name    Pregnancy   Gender
1   Raghad      Yes     Female
1   Raghad      No      Female
2   Ohoud       no      Male
```

What I need is to remove duplicate (in this case 1,1) and to keep one of these rows which has a  pregnancy status of yes.
To clarify, I can't use delete since it's a restricted database. I can only retrieve data.

Comment: database name please

Comment: @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin: It wouldn't help much, if they told us how they named their database. I suppose you want to know the database management system (DBMS)  instead :-)

Comment: @Ohoud 0: The problem is not the query, but the database. Why does it allow the same ID twice in the table? It shouldn't. Why can the same person be pregnant and not pregnant at the same time? Why can the same person be male and female at the same time? There should just be one row per person. Maybe you want a *second* table that contains pregnancy status (along with some date information then of course).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a third party database where they didn't allow us to manipulate the data or have access to database. And it's confidential so I can't provide you with the name of the database. Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Using an exists clause:

```
DELETE
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    pregnancy = 'no' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.pregnancy = 'yes');
```

There are other ways to go about doing this, e.g. using `ROW_NUMBER`, but as you did not tag your database, I offer the above solution which should work on basically any database.

If you want to just view your data with the "duplicates" removed, then use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE
    pregnancy = 'yes' OR
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.pregnancy = 'yes');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response, to clarify, I can't use delete since it's a restricted database. I can only retrieve data.

Comment: Check the updated answer for an option using select.

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help. It is useful. By 1 you mean ID as attribute or as value?

Answer (score 1):

If column `Pregnancy` have just two values "**Yes**" and "**No**", in that case you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` also to get the results.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY Pregnancy DESC) RN
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

In case of multiple values when you want to give highest priorty to "Yes", you can write your query like following

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CASE WHEN Pregnancy = 'Yes' then 0 else 1 end) RN
    FROM TABLE_NAME
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN= 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data you can `group by ID, Name, Gender` and return the maximum value of the column `Pregnancy` for each group since `Yes` is greater compared to `No`:

```
SELECT ID, Name, MAX(Pregnancy) Pregnancy, Gender
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID, Name, Gender
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=808fa35dd9f6ab6ffdd5a38505cec58f).
Results:

```
> ID | Name   | Pregnancy | Gender
> -: | :----- | :-------- | :-----
>  1 | Raghad | Yes       | Female
>  2 | Ohoud  | No        | Male
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of that too! ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot it is really helpful in a simple way. I appreciate your replay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it in MySQL 8. 
Similar Common Table Expressions exist in SQL Server and Oracle.
There you may need to add a comma after then closing parentheses that
ends the CTE (with) definition.

```
with dups as (
 Select id from test
 group by id
 Having count(1) > 1
)
select * from test 
where id in (select id from dups) 
and Pregnancy = 'Yes'
union all 
select * from test where id not in (select id from dups);
```

You can see it in action, by running it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nYio4MjRPrczoZMJ5ZobRa/0)

Note this does it without deleting the original.

But it gives you a result set to work with that has what you want.

If you wanted to delete, then you could use this instead, after the `dups` CTE definition:

```
delete from test 
where id in (select id from dups) and Pregnancy = 'No'
```

Or distill this into:

```
delete from test 
where id in (Select id from test
 group by id
 Having count(1) > 1) and Pregnancy = 'No'
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, update design of your table. `ID` must be `primary key`. This would automatically restrict the duplicate rows having same ID.

2) You can use `Group by` and `having` clause to remove duplicates

```
   delete from table where pregnancy='no' and exists (SELECT 
   id
   FROM table
   GROUP BY id
   HAVING count(id)>1)
```

Comment: This is wrong! You would always have a count of 1 for the two rows with id of 1! Move the and pregnancy test outside!

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate your help.